# Static routes on Cisco

Tags: cisco, router

i have configured 3 static routes on a Cicso router using command

> ip route x.x.x.x [mask] interface name

These routes are however not visible in the routers FIB table.

when I specifically check for static they are shown as

> M  192.168.0.0/24 [1/0] via GigabitEthernet0/3 [N]
>
> M  192.168.1.0/24 [1/0] via GigabitEthernet0/1 [N]
>
> M  192.168.2.0/24 [1/0] via GigabitEthernet0/2 [N]

where [N] for non active.
Why are they non active.
Going by the administrative distance AD of static route is 1. There shoudnt be any overwrite for it in the FIB

Comment: Using an interface name can lead to problems. You should use an IP address as the destination, then you should see them.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

By default, if the interface is down, administratively shutdown or non-connected the route will not be injected into the routing table.  This is a caveat when using interfaces as the next hop instead of an IP address.  There are exceptions to this such as Null interfaces.